# JIRA Search for tasks that are behind schedule

Tags: jira, jql

I want to add a quick filter to a board we have tracking all work, and want clear views of what we have in queue and what we have that is ask risk of missing, so that we can reallocate resources if needed.

I want all work that is at risk of missing its due date:

```
remainingestimate > (due - startofday)
```

I get the following error when I use that query. 
"Error in the JQL Query: Expecting ',' or ')' but got '-'. (line 1, character 26)"

I tried doing:

```
due > startofday(remainingestimate)
```

but i get an error there because in order to do the offset on start of day you need to have a +/- in there, and was getting errors there.

Comment: Maybe https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Time+Tracking+Report can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
remainingEstimate > 0 and duedate < endOfDay() and status not in (Closed, Resolved)
```

There is a little gap, between tasks, they will be (estimated) finnished today, but you like to see those tasks with a risk...